# fetch data from couchdb to node.js file

Tags: node.js, json, couchdb, couchdb-futon

hi everyone i have a probleme whene i want to fetch data from couchdb to file .ejs i have this probleme "Server started on 3000 Port
undefined"

this is my code

```
const express = require('express');  
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');  
const path = require('path');  
const NodeCouchdb = require('node-couchdb');  

 
const couch =new NodeCouchdb({  
auth:{  
user: 'admin'  ,
password: 'admin'  
}  
});  

const dbName = "mydata";

const viewUrl = "_design/_allproducts/_view/all";


couch.listDatabases().then(function(dbs){  
console.log(dbs);  
});  
 
const app = express();  
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');  
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));  
app.use (bodyParser.json());  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));  
app.get('/', function(req,res){  
    couch.get(dbName, viewUrl).then(function(data, headers, status){
                 console.log(data);
                 res.render('views',{mydata:data})
    },
    function(err){

        res.send(err);
    });
});  
app.listen(3000, function(){  
 console.log('Server started on 3000 Port');  
})
```

i try to chenge something on congiration file of couchdb couchdb.init but it's not working

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Can you specify the exact problem you're facing? Are you unable to start the server, or have you started it but can't connect to CouchDB, or is CouchDB not returning any data?

Comment: Following up on @PRATHEESHPC's comment, can you hit your view with `curl` from the command line? Or in a browser window?